# Apache Camel Java 8 Support

Tags: java, java-8, apache-camel, apache-camel-3

In this [blog](https://camel.apache.org/blog/2019/12/Camel3-Whatsnew/) it has been written that Apache Camel will drop the Java 8 support in the mid 3.x versions:

> Java 8 will still be supported for the first number of 3.x releases but is expected to be dropped later in 2020

How can I know precisely from with version the Java 8 support has been dropped? If I'm using Java 8, shall I work with 2.x Apache Camel versions or shall I work with 3.0 for example?

Comment: I guess the usage of Camel and Java version needs to be decided from the Project Architects(If your working in an IT Team). As a Java and Camel developer, My team and I, in our daily development tasks use Camel 2X and Java 1.8. As of now there are no plans to shift to Camel 3x, I guess which only supports Java 8. But its finally depends on the Project Needs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [FAQ](https://camel.apache.org/manual/latest/faq/what-platforms-are-supported.html) (official) Java 8 is still supported with 3.x. If that changes they are bound to write it in the release notes. Furthermore you can always check the [source](https://github.com/apache/camel/blob/main/pom.xml). It is of course your choice, but I would go with 3.x.